# TinyMce not storing html, just raw text (laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, tags, tinymce

So i added TinyMCE with this method

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/myapihere/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
```

and added a textarea later on the text. But for some reason[image]
[image]

This is what i want it to show to me, when the post is updated
This is what it shows me

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that when you output the string from tinyMCE, you get the raw html without any formatting.

I think the problem is how you output the string. When outputting HTML in a blade template, don't use `{{ $content }}`, this will automatically encode html entities.

To output HTML, you have to use `{!! $content !!}`. This will output your string as is and won't parse html entities.